# Error:Cannot change configuration ':android:compile' after it has been resolved

Tags: android, android-studio, import, build.gradle

I tried to add google-play-services.jar to my project but I faced with this err.Why?  `(Error:Cannot change configuration ':android:compile' after it has been resolved.)`
Does anybody know a way to resolve this problem?

Comment: It depends. Where did you put the jar? What's about your build.gradle?

Answer (score 1):

In android studio you don't need to add jar files, Remove the jar file and

1. Open the build.gradle file inside your application module directory.

   > Note: Android Studio projects contain a top-level build.gradle file and a build.gradle file for each module. Be sure to edit the file for your application module
2. Add a new build rule under dependencies for the latest version of play-services. For example:

   ```
   dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
   }
   ```
3. Save the changes and click Sync Project with Gradle Files in the toolbar.

Here's official [link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)